# Can't login to gallery3 due to csrf fail with Firefox

Tags: php, apache, firefox, gallery

Dears!

Maybe someone of yous is familiar with gallery3 and can help me? 
I installed gallery 3.0.9 on a local server with fresh Debian 3.16.51-3 system with

- Apache 2.4.10
- PHP 5.6.33
- MySQL 5.5.59-0

Installation went like a charm, gallery created a new database, a new entry in table users ('admin') with a password. Fine.

For whatever reason, login is not possible after installation with Firefox 58.0.

When trying a logon with Firefox, the gallery login fails with logfile in `/var/www/html/gallery3/var/logs/` throws the following error(s):

```
2018-03-09 12:14:08 +01:00 --- error: Kohana_Exception [ 403 ]: @todo FORBIDDEN
/var/www/html/gallery3/modules/gallery/helpers/access.php [ 202 ]
#0 /var/www/html/gallery3/modules/gallery/helpers/access.php(425): access_Core::forbidden()
#1 /var/www/html/gallery3/modules/gallery/controllers/login.php(31): access_Core::verify_csrf()
#2 [internal function]: Login_Controller->auth_ajax()
#3 /var/www/html/gallery3/system/core/Kohana.php(331): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(Login_Controller), Array)
#4 [internal function]: Kohana_Core::instance(NULL)
#5 /var/www/html/gallery3/system/core/Event.php(208): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /var/www/html/gallery3/application/Bootstrap.php(67): Event_Core::run('system.execute')
#7 /var/www/html/gallery3/index.php(116): require('/var/www/html/g...')
#8 {main}
2018-03-09 12:14:08 +01:00 --- error: Missing messages entry kohana/core.errors.403 for message kohana/core
```

Obviously it's the **`static function verify_csrf()`** in `var/www/html/gallery3/modules/gallery/helpers/access.php` which fails when checking the session tokens.

May anyone experienced the same or similar issues with Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Prevention failing with Firefox (while IE and Chrome working fine)?

Grateful hoping for any advice in this matter,

cheers!

Comment: Just tested and found, that the problem only exists with FireFox (58.0.1 (64-Bit)). The problem neither exists with IE 9/10/11 nor Chrome 65.0.3325.146. Both IE and Chrome works perfectly well. So I will change my research (added Firefox as tag to my question and edited the text respectively) and post results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that worked for me... 
I Disabled HSTS:
1) about:config
2) Right-click: New Integer
3) Name: test.currentTimeOffsetSeconds
4) Value: 11491200

I then ran CCleaner deleting all the cookies and rebooted.
Working for a week now.